# GORM <nil> (\u003cnil\u003e) while Update database

Tags: go, error-handling, orm, go-gorm

```
if res = db.Save(&msg); res.Error != nil {
    log.Error(err)
    return
}
```

I have simple code which is update column in database, but sometimes it gives me `\u003cnil\u003e` (`<nil>`) instead of nil.
Any reason or any experience who have ?